# How to remove subarrays containing nan elements on a 3d array preserving the shape?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have a sparse array of shape *(863, 923, 2)* that contains lot of `NAN`s:

```
[[[ 43.06010628 -11.01121568]
  [ 25.03068277  16.3949826 ]
  [-23.75853158 -10.95350074]
  ...
  [ 25.52110353   3.00428452]
  [ 32.66945663   9.76115107]
  [ 19.1341548    8.48547008]]

 [[ 19.08099208  11.27167832]
  [-29.4360534  -12.39131814]
  [ 11.24612069  14.38915742]
  ...
  [ 16.6897315   10.04601296]
  [ 30.09409518  17.09382562]
  [ -9.47312129  -9.57484782]]

 [[ 21.22006655  -5.01340343]
  [ 11.65512749   2.32398374]
  [-22.14668148 -11.05883399]
  ...
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]]

 ...

 [[ 32.32522443  -3.73563526]
  [ 30.88408144  -2.92184744]
  [ 37.44548043 -21.8209554 ]
  ...
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]]

 [[ 36.85471348  -7.86696711]
  [ 37.20204074  -6.32105844]
  [ 32.32522443  -3.73563526]
  ...
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]]

 [[ 34.21397091  -5.88930588]
  [ 35.88819735  -7.64992589]
  [ 35.48958094 -10.34708285]
  ...
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]
  [         nan          nan]]]
```

I would like to remove all nan-containing subarrays while preserving the dimensionality of the array. My understanding is that the shape of the array will change to something like *(m, n, 2)* but am unable to produce such an array after removing `NAN`s.
Here is my attempt:

```
nonnanarr = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=-1)].reshape((863, -1, 2))
```

And here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\Desktop\observables\my_script.py", line 167, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\username\Desktop\observables\my_script.py", line 104, in main
    time_stamp_num, agents_num, spatial_dimensions_num = dataframe_splitter()
  File "c:\Users\username\Desktop\observables\utilities.py", line 1351, in dataframe_splitter
    nonnan_arr = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=-1)].reshape(
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 226512 into shape (863,newaxis,2)
```

Comment: Do you mean that this should be done before my line?

Comment: I suggest providing a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mre). In particular, I'd put some effort in producing some minimal input with expected output.

Comment: the nan-containing subarrays are not useful information and I want to get rid of all of them.

Comment: Cool, but just removing stuff in random places in an array is not guaranteed to produce an array, e.g. `[[nan, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`, if you drop the nan you will get a jagged array `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`, for which NumPy has next to zero support.

Comment: I understand that but I want to get rid of [nan, 1, 2] subarray completely so long as it has a nan in it. In other words, I want [[3, 4, 5]] and not [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]].

Comment: Once you get to N-dims the problem is similar, unless you want to remove entire (N-1)-dim manifolds. E.g. an array with shape `(a, b, c)` can be made into an array of shape `(a', b', c')` with either `a'=a` and `b'=b`, or `a'=a` and `c'=c`, etc. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Sure, this makes sense. I want to convert from (a, b, c) to (a, b', c) or (a', b, c). In other words, my only constrain is c'=c.

Comment: The error is saying that 226512 elements made it through the filter, but isn't multiple of 863

Comment: I am sure after removing (N-1)-dim manifolds mentioned by norok2 will not preserve the original 863 which is fine as long as I know the exact number that goes in to the shape which I don't know. and thank you for interpreting the error. I did not know that.

Comment: The reshape will work only if the same number of rows are removed from the 923 dimension for each of the 863 blocks.  You may need to experiment with a smaller sample to get a clear idea of what's happening - a sample where you can view the whole array.  Right now you just check for `nan` containing rows.  To your thinking what's a `subarray`?

Comment: The point is that the reduction must happen in N-1 dimensions not 1.

Comment: Thank you norok2, that's an important point. Let's see what I can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an N-dimensional array, you need to reduce your mask along (N-1) dimensions.

In you case, you have `n = 3` dimensions, so you have three ([`comb(n, (n - 1))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb)) possibilities.

For example, with this input:

```py
import numpy as np


arr = np.arange(3 * 4 * 5, dtype=np.float_).reshape((3, 4, 5))
print(arr[1, 1, 1])
# 26
arr[1, 1, 1] = np.nan
print(arr)
# [[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
#   [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
#   [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
#   [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]]

#  [[20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]
#   [25. nan 27. 28. 29.]
#   [30. 31. 32. 33. 34.]
#   [35. 36. 37. 38. 39.]]

#  [[40. 41. 42. 43. 44.]
#   [45. 46. 47. 48. 49.]
#   [50. 51. 52. 53. 54.]
#   [55. 56. 57. 58. 59.]]]
```

You could reduce on `(1, 2)`:

```py
mask1 = np.isnan(arr).any(axis=(1, 2))
print(mask1)
# [False  True False]

print(arr[~mask1, :, :].shape)
# (2, 4, 5)

print(arr[~mask1, :, :])
# [[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
#   [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
#   [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
#   [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]]

#  [[40. 41. 42. 43. 44.]
#   [45. 46. 47. 48. 49.]
#   [50. 51. 52. 53. 54.]
#   [55. 56. 57. 58. 59.]]]
```

or on `(0, 2)`:

```py
mask2 = np.isnan(arr).any(axis=(0, 2))
print(mask2)
# [False  True False False]
print(arr[:, ~mask2, :].shape)
# (3, 3, 5)

print(arr[:, ~mask2, :])
# [[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
#   [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
#   [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]]

#  [[20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]
#   [30. 31. 32. 33. 34.]
#   [35. 36. 37. 38. 39.]]

#  [[40. 41. 42. 43. 44.]
#   [50. 51. 52. 53. 54.]
#   [55. 56. 57. 58. 59.]]]
```

or on `(0, 1)`:

```py
mask3 = np.isnan(arr).any(axis=(0, 1))
print(mask3)
# [False  True False False False]
print(arr[:, :, ~mask3].shape)
# (3, 4, 4)

print(arr[:, :, ~mask3])
# [[[ 0.  2.  3.  4.]
#   [ 5.  7.  8.  9.]
#   [10. 12. 13. 14.]
#   [15. 17. 18. 19.]]

#  [[20. 22. 23. 24.]
#   [25. 27. 28. 29.]
#   [30. 32. 33. 34.]
#   [35. 37. 38. 39.]]

#  [[40. 42. 43. 44.]
#   [45. 47. 48. 49.]
#   [50. 52. 53. 54.]
#   [55. 57. 58. 59.]]]
```

---

For your case, if you need the 3rd dimension to stay the same, you cannot reduce on `(0, 1)`, but any of `(1, 2)` and `(0, 2)` would work. You need to pick the most appropriate for you.

Comment: Interesting! I was not aware of the term "reduction". So, I was doing trial and error to see which two integers will multiply to 226512.